# Visual studio 2019 no option for GitLab when creating a new Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, gitlab, visual-studio-2019

After an update to git extension for Visual studio 2019, the Git functionality has moved from Team Explorer to a new option called Git Changes.

I've created a new solution in VS, then added it to source control using the option from File menu. I then clicked on Git changes -> Create Git Repository...

This opens up the following window:

[image: Dialog Create Git Repository...]

As you can see there is no option for GitLab there. I can only create a new repository in GitHub but there is nothing there for GitLab.

I already have the GitLab VS extesion installed and updated and I've already created many other repositories in GitLab in the past from inside VS. But I can't find a way to do this anymore. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Is this the GitLab extension you're talking about, OP? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MysticBoy.GitLabExtensionforVisualStudio

Comment: @carloswm85 Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft bought Github in 2018 and since VS is a Microsoft product, they're likely trying to encourage users to move to Github instead of its competitors. However, it looks like that "Existing remote" option is what you want (on the left under Other). You should be able to provide the remote url from Gitlab there.

Answer (score 0):

> Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and then toggle
> the New Git user experience checkbox, which will switch you back to
> Team Explorer for Git.

[How to use the full Team Explorer experience in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/git-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#how-to-use-the-full-team-explorer-experience-in-visual-studio)